# <input type='file'> provides URL encoded file name, causing File Not Found error with FileReader on Android native browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, file-upload, filereader

I have an AngularJS web app where I'm using a `<file type='input' accept='image/*'>` for selecting images.

I'm displaying the newly selected image to the user by binding the file input's `change` event, reading it with the `FileReader`'s `readAsDataURL` method and assigning the result to an image's src attribute. In a nutshell it looks like this:

```
input.bind('change', function (evt) {
    var fileList = evt.target.files;
    if (fileList != null) {
       var file = fileList.item(0),
           reader = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
           if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
               // result is assigned to src attribute of an image element
           }
       };

       reader.onerror = function (evt) {
           alert(evt.target.error.code);
       };

       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

This works fine on:

- current desktop browsers
- iOS (except iOS 8.0 because of the known bug that prevents uploading photos and videos from Safari)
- Chrome for Mobile
- most native browsers on Android, **but not all!**

As an example, my HTC One running on Android 4.4.2 sometimes suffers from a **File Not Found** error when trying to read an image from the storage with the FileReader.

I figured that on this device the provided `file.name` is **URL encoded**, turning a file name like *"My Image.jpg"* into *"My%20Image.jpg"*. Since the FileReader takes the file name as is, it simply accesses the "wrong", non existing file. This `NOT_FOUND_ERR` error doesn't happen with file names that are not affected by the URL encoding, e.g. "20141028.jpg".

I tried to URL decode the file name myself before passing it to the FileReader, but since `File.name` is a `read only` property I'm not able to change it.

So I'm wondering, what's the best solution to tackle this "misalignment" of the provided file info?

Comment: You say "I figured that on this device the provided file.name is URL encoded" - do you **figure** this, or do you **know** this is the problem? I'm not sure what else the problem could be (since you showed that "20141028.jpg" can be found, but still)

Comment: the name doesn't have anything to do with reading the file into a dataURL, so it must be something else...

Comment: i would be willing to bet that the file is deleted or locked by another background app in-between the time the list is populated and the file is read.

Comment: @dandavis: If I simply rename a file that already works to contain a space in its name, I get an error when reading it. Renaming it to a "valid" file name again makes it work again. So locking and deleting are not the subject of the problem. Regarding your point about the dataURL: I know that it doesn't simply rely on the file name to access the file, but what is directly affected by a change of the file name is also the path. Therefore, when the file name is affected by the URL encoding, it results in an invalid path, causing the file not found error :(

Comment: @Mobiletainment: well if you put it that way, it sounds like a bug in the browser; not sure there's much you can do to fix it.

Comment: @Ian: I don't know for sure if that's the cause, but at least it's the only difference I spotted. So all the working devices/browsers take the file name as-is (even other Android devices like Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4), but the HTC One provides it URL encoded, followed by a File Not Found error when reading.

Comment: I am getting an weird error. When i am selecting a pdf file, the file name and type is weird. I am getting an empty file type and a different file name other than the original file name. Suppose, my file name is "abc.pdf", but i get the name from filereader as a number like "56670". Also, i am getting the type name as empty. But, if i select an image file, i am getting perfect type and name of the file.

Comment: @SetuBasak I think this is intended behavior and for security reasons. The file name as well as the path of documents is "faked". Often, you even see that the chosen file is contained in a folder called "fakepath".

Comment: @Mobiletainment Is there any way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This my case study but old hint.
me development mobile Web app Android it possible now case.
HTML Tag is

`<input type='file' accept='image/*;capture=camera' onchange='open File(event)'>`

it change.
before this html tag not select file, but after html tag select. for Chrome and Android Chrome.
thank.